# Can you file for employment insurance if you still own a business that makes 10,000 a year without work in Canada?

Tags: canada, unemployment

Can you file for employment insurance if you still own a business that makes $10,000 a year without work in Canada? Let's say you lose a job, not by your own fault, that made you $90,000 a year, but you're still making 10,000 a year in a side business that doesn't require you to put more than 1 hour every month, can you still apply for employment insurance and get $1,500 cheques every month in Canada?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but you must report the income (gross income - operating expenses) in the week when the work was performed. It probably will reduce the EI payment for that week.

[Self employment other than farming](https://www.canada.ca/en/services/benefits/ei/earnings-chart.html#self1)

Comment: Does that include income generated from past work? Because it says income from service.

Comment: @Sayaman That I'm not sure about but in general they talk about assigning the "income" to whatever week the work was performed, even if money will be received later.

Comment: Ok, I was wondering, because in the theoretical situation I was thinking about it was performed before the insurance. Let's say I made some music and I am getting income from a music song I wrote like 1 or 2 years ago.